# Getting error trying to save GIF screenshot via Excel VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am using below link to take screenshot of excel and save as .gif file:

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/xl2gif.htm

When I try to run the macro, it gives following error at "containerbok.Activate":

Run time error '424': Object Required

May I know why I am getting this error?

I am using Excel 2010

Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me (Excel 2003).

Comment: Can you please try on Excel 2010?

Comment: I'd like to... but only 2003 available :-(

Comment: I can't get it to work in 2010.  I think they changed the chart exporting feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things are actually a little simpler than the code in the link that you posted.  Just select the range of cells you want to image, and then run the following code.

```
 Sub ExportSelection()

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        'Copy the area that you have selected as a picture.
        Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
        'Create a default bar(column) chart using the selected cells.
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        'Remove all the data from the chart, leaving a blank chart.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
        Next
        'Paste the image of the selected cells onto the chart.
        ActiveChart.Paste
        'Export the chart as a gif image.
        ActiveChart.Export Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\chart.gif"
        'Delete the existing chart.
        ActiveChart.Parent.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

The key piece is `ActiveChart.Export`

This has been tested in Excel 2010 and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But being a newbie, I didn't understand how what you have written will affect the code which is there in that link. Do I have to remove "containerbok.Activate". I mean what code should I write to avoid getting that error? Can you post modified code please..I really appreciate your help

Comment: All you need is the Sub and End Sub to make the code complete.  This code that Stewbob posted and nothing from the other link.  I added the Sub and End Sub, an If statement to make sure the selection was a range, and moved the export to desktop (because I got a permission error trying to save to the root in Win 7).  Works as advertised for me in 2010 - Nice work Stewbob